# how to i trigger this code with an onclick event. I have tried and failed

Tags: javascript, function, events

I cant seem to trigger the code when i click the div box it just keeps running onload.

```
<div id='tank' onclick="timer"  style="position:relative; left:100px; top:240px;border-       radius:360px;
 background-color:green; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">

(function () {
// don't leak variables into the global scope - think "variable = carbon dioxide"
    var elem = document.getElementById('tank'), pos = 100,
       timer = setInterval(function() {
        pos++;
        elem.style.left = pos+"px";
        if( pos == 290) clearInterval(timer);

      },12);
  })();
```

Comment: It runs onload because you set it to self-invoke and you have no onclick handler set on the div.

Answer (score 2):

```
(function () {
   //...
}());
```

immediately runs the code inside the function, so it is no wonder that your code runs on page load.

```
onclick="timer"
```

simply does nothing. It's the same as writing something like:

```
var foo = 42;
foo; // <- this does not do anything
```

Even worse, if `timer` is not defined, this will throw an error (which is the case in your example).

What you have to do is assigning a function as click event handler to the element. For example:

```
document.getElementById('tank').onclick = function() {
    var elem = this, 
        pos = 100,
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            pos++;
            elem.style.left = pos+"px";
            if( pos == 290) clearInterval(timer);

        },12);
};
```

*(and remove `onclick="timer"` from your HTML)*

I recommend to read [the excellent articles at quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) to learn more about event handling.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='tank' onclick="timer()"  style="position:relative; left:100px; top:240px;border-radius:360px; background-color:green; height:100px; width:100px;">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function timer (){
    alert("h");
    var elem = document.getElementById('tank'), pos = 100,
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        pos++;
        elem.style.left = pos+"px";
        if( pos == 290) clearInterval(timer);

      },12);
}
</script>
```

Slight modification to your code.